# use of c4.5 for sentiment analysis

Tags: decision-tree

I need to apply the use of the C4.5 algorithm in a sentiment analysis case study about a product review. I have searched for a long time but still have not found the form of the C4.5 algorithm.

Can you help me to provide a C4.5 algorithm that can be used in a sentiment analysis case study that processes a product review file, where files containing various reviews of a product can be differentiated into positive or negative reviews?

`sentiment` `analysis` `phyton` `decision-tree`

Comment: Does this help? A C4.5 algorithm for english emotional classification -  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s12530-017-9180-1

Comment: If you are initiating the sentiment analysis - just start with Naive Bayes, Support Vector Machines and  RNN derivatives LSTM and GRU would also be a good choice in deep learning.